# Not able to place $_SESSION['user'] value (saved in page1) in an input field inside page 2

Tags: php

Don't know were is the mistake lies in the code.

// Code in Page1

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
  <title>Test1</title>  
</head>  
<body>
  <FORM METHOD = "POST" action = "Page2.php">
    <input type="text" name = "user">  
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
  </FORM>
  <?php 
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  }
  ?>
</body>  
</html>
```

// Code in Page2

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
  <title>Test2</title>  
</head>  
<body>
  <input type="text" name = "field3" value = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']); ?>>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the input field-named as "field3" in Page2 to be filled with whatever value provided in field-named as "name" of Page1.

Comment: The form value of the user is posted to Page2, yet you try process it in Page1. Therefore it is never stored in the session.

Comment: `value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']); ?>"`

Comment: Probably you have missed quotes `"`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, kindly elaborate. which line of code is trying to process it in Page1.

Comment: @ZainFarooq. Thanks I added it. But still not getting result.

Comment: You seem to have no clue what your own code is doing. Is this a real question? It's the PHP piece in Page1, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action page is page2 so you will never have a post action on the page 1 where you have html form. In case of you have `POST` action that leads to page 1 you still have issues on page2.

and On page2, change it as

```
value =" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']); ?>">
```

You are missing `"`

Comment: He has some different problem

Answer (score 2):

You are posting data to page2 when submitting the form

```
<FORM METHOD = "POST" action = "Page2.php">
```

The code which is inside the if statement never executed `if (isset($_POST["submit"])){`

You have to place if statement on Page2 at the top after `session_start` to make it work

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])){
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
}
```